# Adding labels to grid lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I'm building a custom map for ATV trails in QGIS 3.4.  Is it possible to add a label to a gridline on the map surface in a layout?  I've already labelled the gridline around the frame but would like to add one on the map itself.  Example attached.[image: Sample from Canadian topographic map.]

Comment: Do the gridlines have coordinates as attributes?

Comment: Yes, the gridlines correspond to UTM or lat/long coordinates. I haven't decided which way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a second grid in the layout, with an offset for the coordinates. Indeed you may need two, one for the latitude and a second one for the longitude, if you want to properly align both labels.

[image: Layout grid - labels inside]

The alternative would be to construct the grid as a vector layer, which you can label as you wish.

Comment: The first approach is the simplest and would work except that my map is rotated -37 degrees to optimize layout of area on page.  The labels do not remain aligned with the grid when shifted inside the map area.  The second would work better in my case and i will go that direction.  Thank you for the suggestions.