# QGIS problem with labelling grids

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I would like to label my grids in QGIS. I know the Printing Layout option presented i.e. here

https://geoafrikana.com/how-add-grids-and-grid-frame-map-qgis/

but yet as the layer.
I want them as presented in the image below:

[image]

I found some hints here:

[Adding labels to grid lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329544/adding-labels-to-grid-lines-in-qgis)

but they didn't helped me.

I would like to know what placement or rendering options should be applied for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

1. Set up a rule based label with two rules. As filter set for the first one: `x_min($geometry) = x_min(layer_property(@layer,'extent'))` and for the second one: `y_max($geometry) =y_max(layer_property(@layer,'extent'))`
2. Set up a custom `Placement -> Geometry Generator`. Enter this expression for the first rule: `make_point(x_min($geometry)-bounds_width($geometry)/2,y($geometry))` and this for the second rule: `make_point(x($geometry),y_max($geometry)+bounds_width($geometry)/2)`
3. Result:
   [image]
4. A settings-example:
   [image]

Adjust the placement if needed a little.